# Order post by meta value with semicolon

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-key

I had a post type music. For which i created custom field Music length. Which store music duration in this format like 01:50
I want to display post on order by Music length. I had use both order by meta_value and meta_value_num. But it does not work. My code to get post is:

```
<code>
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'music',
  'meta_key' => 'length',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$pop_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
</code>
```

My question is how to order the post by its meta value in semicolon format(01:50, 02:46, 03:04, 02:37). So the post with meta value 03:04 comes first then 02:46 and so on! Is there any way?

Comment: See this refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6158726/php-compare-time ans this -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36609349/compare-the-current-date-to-a-timestamp-in-wordpress-with-meta-query

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'music',
  'meta_key' => 'length',
  'orderby' => "REPLACE(meta_value_num, ':', '')",
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'posts_per_page' => 10
);
$pop_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But note that it will be very slow for large datasets as it has to recompute the new string for every row.

Comment: 'orderby' => "REPLACE(meta_value_num, ':', '')", does not work

Comment: did you get any error? As I run the same query with same data structure

Comment: it didn't show any error. It display all posts but not in proper order.

Comment: where did you get this code 'orderby' => "REPLACE(meta_value_num, ':', '')" the REPLACE method. Is there any documentation

Comment: can you post your raw sql query here